# Is there a good way to get distinct values in large collections in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, distinct

I try to get all the distinct value (less than 10 possible values) of a given field in a large collection (3.500.000 docs, 35gb).

I tried to get these values with a `db.collection.distinct('field')`, but it is very slow, even if there is an index (it doesn't seems to be used).

Any suggestions to improve performance on this query?

Thanks

**Edit**
I was using Mongo 2.4.9. It has been fixed in 2.5.5 (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2094), but I still have a performance issue on queries like this `db.logs.distinct( "version", {wsId: "XXX" })` even if indexes exists for both fields.

Comment: can you show your document structure, indexes and explain output

Comment: I just edited my question. I'm using a 2.4.9 version, it seems that performance has been improved in 2.5.5.

Comment: The document stored is pretty simple. It is a document without nested field, the field (resultCode) has a simple index.

{
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
                "resultCode" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "app_logs.logs",
        "name" : "resultCode_1"
}

Comment: That JIRA would only help if you have say, a small amount of unique values that can be easily skipped allowing distinct to iterate over only a small part of the index. How many distinct values are we looking at here?

Comment: Less than 10, so I guess it is going to resolve my performance issues

Comment: Easily, I would definitely try upgrading

Comment: Since the upgrade, performance are really good on a simple distinct, but on a distinct with a query such as `db.logs.distinct( "version", {wsId: "XXX" }) `, performance are really bad again (even with indexes on theses fields : {wsId:1, version:1}, {version:1, wsId:1}, {wsId:1}, {version:1}). Any ideas?

Comment: Most likely version has a lot of values, in this case there is no easy way around this, the command cannot shortcut the index and it cannot just guess, it has to look at every single one, hmm there is no easy way around this

Comment: There is only 10 differents versions and 5 differents wsId in the whole DB.
I just want to get the versions that are used for a given wsId. It looks like the indexes are not used when I add a condition to a distinct query. Am I right?

Comment: I think I know why, it is because MongoDB will only use one index here. Hmm this is an interesting one, it can't use a compound since technically the query is different from the project...hmm

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why, but I'm going to trust you on this one ! 
 
I tried to try to solve this problem by changing my point of vue and by using an aggregation, and the performance are still terrible : 
`db.logs.aggregate([
    {$project: { _id: 0, wsId: 1, version:1 }},
    {$group:{ _id: "$wsId", version: {$addToSet: "$version"} }}
])`

Comment: Ah there is a way to do this, hang on, if you use `{$sort:version}, {$group:{ _id: "$version"}}` that should make the group pick from index, see if that helps

Comment: I'm not going to work on this project until next monday. I'll let you know, but it might work

Comment: Well ... Still not working. `db.logs.aggregate([ {$sort:{version:1}}, {$group:{_id: "$version"}}])` doesn't end, so I'm not going to try to add a condition on that query ...

Answer (score 11):

"distinct" makes use of the the index if its available. Run it like this and see if index is being used:

```
db.runCommand({distinct: "collectionNameGoesHere", key:"fieldNameGoesHere"})
```

the last value in the returned result set is stats that looks like this:

```
   "stats" : {
           "n" : 280,
           "nscanned" : 280,
           "nscannedObjects" : 0,
           "timems" : 0,
           "cursor" : "BtreeCursor class_id_1"
   }
```

Notice that my query had used an index on the class_id field since I had pre-made it.

Comment: I thnk the OP already knows this, his question is particular to a subset of index usage of distinct.

Comment: Indeed, I already done that? With an upgrade of Mongo, the index is now used if I make a simple distinct query, but if I add a condition on this query, the performance is terrible.

Comment: I have used db.runCommand({distinct: "collectionNameGoesHere", key:"fieldNameGoesHere"}) but got error message. errmsg exception: distinct too big, 16mb cap

Comment: @Sammaye, I'm using mongodb 4.2, and conditional distinct and count are still terrible. Is there any modern workaround, as I see this post is around 6 years old.

Comment: @Zeeshan aggregation framework is probably your best bet

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit old, but I faced a similar issue now and ended up with the solution of caching distinct values (since in my case they are rarely changed)

Might be helpful for someone.

```
import datetime
import pickle
import redis    

def get_distinct_values(collection, column_name):
    redis = Redis(settings.REDIS_SERVER, settings.REDIS_PORT)
    key = "distinct_{}".format(column_name)
    if not redis.exists(key):
        res = list(collection.distinct(column_name))
        redis.set(key, pickle.dumps(res))
        redis.expire(key, datetime.timedelta(days=1))
    else:
        res = pickle.loads(redis.get(key))
    return res
```